# Fine Uploader: resizing large files before upload?

Tags: file-upload, fine-uploader

I'm evaluating [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com/) compared to various other options, specifically [JQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/).

I generally prefer the Fine Uploader approach as it's more lightweight, compared to JQuery File Uploader which has dependencies on Bootstrap and JQuery UI.

However it's important to be able to resize images: e.g., **a user may select a large file from their camera and this may be very large - uploading the full resolution photo may take a very long time**. JQuery File Upload doe this.

Additionally we don't have much use for very high resolution files.

If possible (I'm aware some browsers may not support this), I'd like to be able to resize images client size.

Is this possible?

Comment: This feature is now complete in the develop branch, and is a planned part of the upcoming 4.4 release.  Read more at http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/develop/features/scaling.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fine Uploader does not currently have any native support for image manipulation.  This is a feature in our backlog, but we have not had many users tell us they are interested in this.  This is one of the reasons why such a feature has yet to be implemented natively.  There is a case, [#707](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/707) that marks the start of native image-editing support for Fine Uploader.  It is *tentatively* scheduled for 4.0.

However, you can certainly make use of `FileReader` and `Canvas` to resize the image.  You can then submit this resized image as a `Blob` to Fine Uploader via the `addFiles` API method.  At that point, the file has been submitted and Fine Uploader is ready to upload the item.

Essentially, the steps you would follow to handle this specific scenario, before Fine Uploader natively supports image manipulation:

1. Provide your own file input element(s) or make use of Fine Uploader's file/folder drag and drop support to get a handle on some files selected by the user.
2. Use `FileReader` to read the contents of the image.
3. `FileReader` will provide you with a URL for the image, assign that to the `src` attribute of an `img` element.
4. Draw the `img` onto a `canvas` element.  This is where the resizing occurs.
5. Grab the URL of the resized image from the `canvas` element (`canvas.toDataURL(...)`).
6. Convert the URL to a `Blob`.
7. Pass  the `Blob` to the `addFiles` API method of Fine Uploader.

The intent is to take care of most if not all of this for integrators such as yourself in the future by adding native image manipulation support to Fine Uploader.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Ray! I'm aware of the canvas trick, I'll try and integrate it as you mentioned. Any ideas when 4.0 is due?

Comment: @nailer Fine Uploader just underwent a transfer of ownership.  At this time, the dust is still settling.  We will be going through all of the scheduled features and re-prioritizing them.  Additional resources are going to be assigned to the project to speed things up a bit.  Once we have the team assembled, more updates regarding planned milestones will be provided.  Right now, I'm carrying on as I was before while we hire/allocate more resources for Fine Uploader.  Feel free to have a look at the [issue/feature tracker](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues) and add/comment on items.

Comment: @Ray Nicholus you have any example